# MySQL Order By Issue on large table

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by, innodb

I have the following mysql command:

```
SELECT e.sIndex01 
FROM e_entity e 
WHERE e.meta_oid=336799 
ORDER BY e.sIndex02
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `e_entity` (
  `OID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `E_E_OID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNIQUE_IDX` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `APP_OID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `META_OID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `STORE_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `REL_DISPLAY` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX01` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX02` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX03` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX04` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX05` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX06` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX07` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX08` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX09` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX10` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX11` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX12` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX13` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX14` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX15` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX16` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX17` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX18` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX19` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `SINDEX20` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `NINDEX01` double NOT NULL,
  `NINDEX02` double NOT NULL,
  `NINDEX03` double NOT NULL,
  `NINDEX04` double NOT NULL,
  `NINDEX05` double NOT NULL,
  `NINDEX06` double NOT NULL,
  `NINDEX07` double NOT NULL,
  `NINDEX08` double NOT NULL,
  `NINDEX09` double NOT NULL,
  `NINDEX10` double NOT NULL,
  `DINDEX01` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DINDEX02` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DINDEX03` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DINDEX04` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DINDEX05` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DINDEX06` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DINDEX07` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DINDEX08` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DINDEX09` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DINDEX10` datetime NOT NULL,
  `FREETEXT` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `UID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OID`),
  KEY `App_Parent` (`META_OID`),
  KEY `sindex01` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX01`(64)),
  KEY `sindex02` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX02`(64)),
  KEY `sindex03` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX03`(64)),
  KEY `sindex04` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX04`(64)),
  KEY `sindex05` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX05`(64)),
  KEY `sindex06` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX06`(64)),
  KEY `sindex07` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX07`(64)),
  KEY `sindex08` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX08`(64)),
  KEY `sindex09` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX09`(64)),
  KEY `sindex10` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX10`(64)),
  KEY `nindex01` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX01`),
  KEY `nindex02` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX02`),
  KEY `nindex03` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX03`),
  KEY `nindex04` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX04`),
  KEY `nindex05` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX05`),
  KEY `dindex01` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX01`),
  KEY `dindex02` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX02`),
  KEY `dindex03` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX03`),
  KEY `dindex04` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX04`),
  KEY `dindex05` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX05`),
  KEY `sindex11` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX11`(64)),
  KEY `sindex12` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX12`(64)),
  KEY `sindex13` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX13`(64)),
  KEY `sindex14` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX14`(64)),
  KEY `sindex15` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX15`(64)),
  KEY `sindex16` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX16`(64)),
  KEY `sindex17` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX17`(64)),
  KEY `sindex18` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX18`(64)),
  KEY `sindex19` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX19`(64)),
  KEY `sindex20` (`META_OID`,`SINDEX20`(64)),
  KEY `nindex06` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX06`),
  KEY `nindex07` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX07`),
  KEY `nindex08` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX08`),
  KEY `nindex09` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX09`),
  KEY `nindex10` (`META_OID`,`NINDEX10`),
  KEY `dindex06` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX06`),
  KEY `dindex07` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX07`),
  KEY `dindex08` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX08`),
  KEY `dindex09` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX09`),
  KEY `dindex10` (`META_OID`,`DINDEX10`),
  KEY `E_E_OID` (`E_E_OID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=469158 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The above query takes a couple of minutes to complete, however without the `order by` clause it takes only 5 seconds, so clearly there's a bottleneck on `order by`. There are 471000 rows in the table, and the matching result set where I assume `order by` is executed is 171000 rows. What suggestions can I follow to improve performance?

Comment: **255** characters is the maximum index length. But the size of your varchar column is `1024`

Comment: @1000111 The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.

Comment: But the index is made up of (`META_OID`,`SINDEX01`(64)), which is 75 characters max

Comment: There are numerous reasons why it is bad to splay an array across columns; it is also bad to have so many indexes.  Please elaborate on what the _intent_ of these columns in; we may be able to find a workaround, but it may not involve the specific approach you are currently taking.

Comment: Also, I see `OFFSET`; do you intend to "paginate" through the rows?

Comment: Prefix indexes are nearly always useless.  Do you have any queries that make use of them?

Comment: I have removed the prefixes to include the full columns, it's faster now. And yes I'm paginating through the rows

Comment: See [_here_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) for discussion of why `OFFSET` is a slow and error-prone way to do pagination and an efficient workaround.

Comment: I is the query I/O-bound?  How many different values are there for `META_OID`?  Please provide `SHOW INDEXES FROM sIndex01 ;`  (I may have another speedup.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL cannot use your prefixed index `sIndex02` to `order by`, as stated in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY, although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the WHERE clause. These cases include the following:
>
> - There is an index on only a prefix of a column named in the ORDER BY clause. In this case, the index cannot be used to fully resolve the sort order. For example, if only the first 10 bytes of a CHAR(20) column are indexed, the index cannot distinguish values past the 10th byte and a filesort will be needed.

The filesort will require to read all 171k rows from the table before applying the `limit`. So to speed up your query, you have to have the whole column in your index to support `order by`, which is not possible without some slight modifications to your table.

First, enable the configuration option [`innodb_large_prefix`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) (if you use MySQL < 5.7.7, otherwise it is enabled by default) to increase the key size limit to 3072 bytes.

Then either change your charmap of your `SINDEXxx`-columns to anything that uses 1 byte per character (e.g. `latin1`), because `utf8` will use (up to) 3 bytes, thus barely exceeding the key size limit, or, if that is not possible because you actually need `utf8`-characters in that column, slightly reduce your column length to e.g. 1022.

If all of that is not possible (because you need `utf8` and a length of 1024), you can add an additional column for each `sindexxx` with a length of 1022, add a trigger (or a generated column) that stores the first 1022 chars, add an index using `META_OID` and that new column and `order by` that one - assuming you can live with not ordering by the last 2 characters. But since you just have 171k rows, the first 1022 characters should hopefully be significant enough.

Comment: If I restart the mysql service and `innodb_large_prefix` reverts back to its original value, will it cause any issues?

Comment: Your table will keep working if it reverts back. But as soon as you alter the table in any way (e.g. add a column), it will shrink your index to a smaller size (without asking, just shows a warning), so you should set that option in your config file to make it permanent. Same for `innodb_file_format = BARRACUDA`, which I forgot to mention (and is a prerequisit for `innodb_large_prefix`), and you need to change your table to `row_format=dynamic`. There is not much downside to using this (and it will become the default in 5.7), except you cannot downgrade to 5.1 without some effort anymore.

Comment: I'm using `row_format=compressed` is there any major difference?

Comment: Interestingly I have also found that the searches run faster if only the column is indexed, as opposed to (`META_OID`, `SINDEX01`), so if I index only by `SINDEX01` it runs faster

Comment: @RafaelDiaz `row_format=compressed` works too, both support long keys. If an index just on `sindex01` runs faster, you are either not searching for `e.meta_oid=336799` but e.g. `e.meta_oid>336799`, or it is not using the first index for `order by` (e.g. if you did not decrease to 1022 or changed to `latin1`). Check/post your `explain`. If you just use `sindex01`, it doesn't have to do the filesort, it will walk through the index, read the table for each row(!) until it found 100 entries for `meta_oid` (without looking up `meta_oid` via index). In your use case (many rows for each ...

Comment: ... `e.meta_oid`, so much filesort after filtering) this might only require to read some 100 rows and it might be a viable option too. But if you have other values with just some rows (e.g. <100), or if you look for `OFFSET 100000`, the query will be slower then, because it will require random lookup for full table (which is worse than a full table scan without any indexes), but you save the filesort after the search. So if the other two options are not possible, and this is your normal use case, you might work with it.

Comment: Also need `innodb_file_per_table`.

Comment: @Solarflare Why this query is taking 6 minutes to complete? If meta_oid is indexed? `SELECT * FROM e_entity WHERE meta_oid=336799 LIMIT 300000` The table has around 500000 rows, and 201000 rows match this select statement. When I run a `EXPLAIN`, `Extra` is null and it's picking up the correct index in `key`

Comment: @RafaelDiaz If mysql uses the index, it has to jump back and forth in the table to read the rows it found via the index. It is much much slower to read 200k rows that way (jumping back and forth) compared to just reading the whole table from start to end with just 500k rows in one go (It's similar to the "fragmentation" of a hdd). As soon as you get a significant percentage (something between maybe 3% and 10%, but it depends on your setup, your system and your table) of your rows, a full table scan is faster than using the index. Try to force your primary key or use `ignore index`.

Comment: This query takes one minute longer `SELECT * FROM e_entity IGNORE INDEX (App_Parent) WHERE meta_oid=336799 LIMIT 300000`

Comment: @RafaelDiaz You would have to ignore all indexes that can be used to look for `meta_oid`. Use `force index (primary)` instead to keep it short. On a different subject: You should start new questions for this (well, for the next question, because this is hopefully resolved now). The purpose of stack overflow is to a) get the answer to your problem and b) to allow others to find that answer too if they have the same problem. The latter is not possible if the answer is hidden in the comments of a different question. You can send me the link to your new problem if you want me to have a look at it.

Comment: @Solarflare I agree this has gone off topic a bit, I have another issue also related to mysql, would be very grateful if you could take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358169/mysql-performance-in-or-operator

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Non Cluster index for order by and where clause.Please follow link

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: This Answer is irrelevant.  All InnoDB secondary keys are "non-clustered".