# MySQL Performance in OR operator

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `e_relationship` (
`OID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`E_E_OID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`E_E_OID2` int(11) NOT NULL,
`REL_DISPLAY` text NOT NULL,
`APP_OID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`META_OID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`STORE_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
`UID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`OID`),
KEY `Left_Entity` (`E_E_OID`),
KEY `Right_Entity` (`E_E_OID2`),
KEY `Meta_Left` (`META_OID`,`E_E_OID`),
KEY `Meta_Right` (`META_OID`,`E_E_OID2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=310169 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The following query takes about 2.5-3ms, the result set is 1,290 rows, and the total number of rows in the table is 1,008,700:

```
SELECT * FROM e_relationship WHERE e_e_oid=@value1 OR e_e_oid2=@value1
```

This is result of `EXPLAIN`:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: e_relationship
type: index_merge
possible_keys: Left_Entity,Right_Entity
key: Left_Entity,Right_Entity
key_len: 4,4
ref: NULL
rows: 1290
Extra: Using union(Left_Entity,Right_Entity); Using where
```

I would like to speed up this query as this is being quite critical in my system, I'm not sure if I'm reaching some sort of bottleneck in mysql as the number of records has already passed one million, and would like to know about other possible strategies to improve performance.

Comment: 2.5-3 ms seems more than reasonable given the number of rows and the distribution of data.

Comment: you can try IN operator.

Comment: First (and as Mihai stated), 3ms is quite a good response time for a 1M records table. Second, try to monitor the SYSTEM (CPU, MEMORY, DISK) and see if any of those reaches high percent.

Comment: What's wrong with 2.5 - 3 ms to get the response back? What's the number you're after? There's **absolutely nothing wrong here**.

Comment: @ShadabFaiz He's testing two different columns, so `IN` won't work.

Comment: According to the explain, MySQL already uses index merge optimisation for your query, this is as fast as you can get without using an explicit union. You said in a comment to the deleted answer that the union was slower. This is as far as you can get as a developer. From this point on, hand the task over to the DBA, who can fine tune MySQL settings to boost the query's performance. However, I tend to agree with the opinion that 2-3ms seems a reasonably fast performance.

Comment: What sort of parameters would we be looking after?

Comment: What's the number of milliseconds that you are after? Apparently, for some reason, you think that 2.5 - 3 ms is insufficient. That means you have a number that **is sufficient**. What is that number? How can you optimize for performance if you haven't got your numbers?

Comment: Your query is optimized as it is, and 3ms is a good result. If you don't need all columns and add a covering index, you can save the table lookup (to test it, try `select id from` instead of `select * from`), but otherwise, it depends on external factors: how you call your query (e.g. use prepared statements in php), how many/what other queries run, and your overall database performance (so mostly: server price). Estimate: For 1M rows (if the `text` column isn't too large), your query, run directly in MySQL on an idle (halfway recent) cpu with enough ram, shouldn't show anything but 0.000sec.

Comment: Having no idea what the data is. It already looks wrong that you have 2 columns which are so closely named. You currently need an index merge to get the result which I imagine is most of the query execution time. Split the data and then index the resulting tables

Comment: @exussum I don't understand

Comment: `E_E_OID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`E_E_OID2` int(11) NOT NULL,  They are likely the same thing, Should they be in another table ?

Comment: "another table" -- that leads to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes MySQL has trouble optimizing `OR` queries. In this case, you can split it up into two queries using `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM relationship WHERE e_e_oid = @value1
UNION
SELECT * FROM relationship WHERE e_e_oid2 = @value2
```

Each subquery will make use of the appropriate index, and then the results will be merged.

However, in simple cases MySQL can automatically perform this transformation, and it's doing so in your query. That's what `Using union` in the `EXPLAIN` output means.

Comment: This takes even longer

Answer (score 0):

Have a table of `E_E_OIDs`.  It would have (up to) 2 rows per `e_relationship`.  Then

```
SELECT ...
    FROM eeoids AS ee
    JOIN e_relationship AS er ON er.ooid = ee.oid
```

And change from 2 columns to one.  And get rid of 2 of the indexes.

Does the effect of the OR even faster than `UNION`.

(Remaining details left to reader.)

**Analogy**

Suppose a person has several phone numbers (landline, cell, work, etc), and I want to look up his record based on a single phone number.  So, I build a table of `phone`:`personID` pairs and index that on `phone`.  Then I do

```
SELECT ...
    FROM Phones AS nums
    JOIN Persons AS x ON x.personID = nums.personID
    WHERE nums.phone = '123-555-1212'
```

Note:  There is no phone number in the `Persons` table.

Your `E_E_OID` is like my `phone`.

Comment: Will a join not be counterproductive?

Comment: `JOIN` will _probably_ be less overhead than `OR` or `UNION` or `index merge`.

Comment: But `JOIN` is not a replacement but an addition, surely I still need an `OR` and an `index merge` on the `E_E_OIDs` table

Comment: Are you looking up _one_ OID?  Or two?

Comment: I need to filter by `E_E_OID` and `E_E_OID2`

Comment: Let me rephrase my question.  Is `@value1` the same as `@value2`?

Comment: Yes it is, I have amended my question to make it clearer

Comment: OK, my Answer applies.  See the Analogy I added to my answer.

Comment: Your answer doesn't apply, although I filter by the same value, `e_e_oid` and `e_e_oid2` are different values, I want to get the relationships of a certain object whether this is on the left OR the right side of the relationship

Comment: Well, one of us is missing something.

Comment: I was missing your point regarding two records per relationship, I have attempted this placing an index on `e_e_oid` on the new table and it takes  about 8 milliseconds more than my original query